# Why I can't get the variable parameter to other page of blade (HTML)

Tags: php, html, laravel

I confuse regarding my codes this is basically this is a php code using isset GET to get the variable name of parameter. however why my if statement always give me a return of false.

**In my customer_data.blade.php**

```
<td><a href="/customize_customer_order/id={{$detail->customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></td>
```

**The page that i will pass the variable customize_customer_order.blade.php**

```
if(isset($_GET['id'])){
    $product_id = $_GET['id'];
    echo $product_id;
} else {
    echo "failed";
}
```

[image]

Comment: The id in your url is not actually a GET param. GET params start with ?

Comment: hi @devk what do you mean for this?

Answer (score 0):

you are missing a "?" variables are passed along following a "?"

```
example
/test/demo_form.php?name1=value1&name2=value2
```

In this example you could use $_GET['name1'] to get value1

so your code should look like this:

```
<td><a href="/customize_customer_order?id={{$detail->customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

since you are using laravel, you can actually make the code more neater, your route can be something like this

```
Route::get('/customize_customer_order/{id},'Controller');
```

then you have this part you wrote

```
<td><a href="/customize_customer_order/{{$detail->customer_id}}"  class="btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-cart-arrow-down"></i></a></td>
```

then using laravel request you can get the value of the id like so

```
$id=$request->input('id')
```

rather than testing for isset, laravel does that behind the scene. hope it works for you

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass that parameter to controller and from controller to view and than you can access that variable in view file.

For Example :

```
Route::get('/mypage/{$id}','Controllername@methodname');
```

Inside the controller file.

```
function methodname($id){

    return view('test',['id' => $id])
}
```

Now in view file you can access $id variable directly.